# Macbook Pro boots with full screen brightness and keyboard backlight

Tags: 12.04, macbook, brightness, backlight

I have dual-booted my Macbook Pro with Ubuntu 12.04 . Whenever i log-in to Ubuntu, it does so with full screen brightness and keyboard backlight at full . How do i get rid of this? How can i tweak the start-up setting for screen brightness and disable keyboard backlight at start-up?

Comment: see also http://askubuntu.com/questions/137355/how-to-disable-macbook-keyboard-backlight

Answer (score 2):

To fix the screen brightness on my Macbook I stopped the `apple_bl` kernel module from being loaded. This seem to fix this for me.

1. Create a file called: `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-applebl.conf`
2. In the above file add the line:

   ```
    blacklist apple_bl
   ```
3. Reboot.

Comment: I tried this, but it still reboots with maximum brightness.

Comment: OK i read the question wrong. My install also always starts at full brightnesss. But I usually use suspend.

Can you control the brightness using the keys?

Comment: Yep i can use the keys to control the brightness.

Answer (score 2):

Keyboard backlight is only partially implemented, I think. It's working for unity, but in KDE there's no UI for it. You can manually change the keyboard backlight brightness on the command line. I don't have a mac, so I'm not sure what the exact command is, but for my samsung, the command is

```
echo 5 > /sys/class/leds/samsung\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
```

(you have to do this as root, you can use `sudo -s`)

For the mac, have a look in `/sys/class/leds`, and see what's there.

Answer (score 2):

On my 11.2 MacBook Pro running Ubuntu 13.10, I got satisfactory results with this command, which makes an upstart task to dim them upon starting the login screen:

```
sudo cat > /etc/init/mbp-save-battery.conf << EOF
description "Lower screen and keyboard backlight brightness on boot"

task

start on login-session-start

script
  # lower screen brightness
  echo "35" > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

  # Somebody else turns on the keyboard backlight
  # Wait for them before turning it off.
  sleep 1
  echo "0" > /sys/class/leds/smc\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
end script
EOF
```

The sleep for the keyboard backlight control is not ideal, but it has worked every time for me.

Comment: I should note that the keyboard backlight occasionally turns itself back on. Not sure what causes that.

Answer (score 0):

Has been a long time that you asked this question. I had a similar problem and solved it this way:

http://blog.christian-hufgard.de/keyboardscreen_backlight_settings_ubuntu_12_04-2012-07-30

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also, **please edit this post at least to include explicit disclosure that this is *your blog***. [**Our policy requires this when linking in answers to a site with which you are affiliated.**](http://askubuntu.com/faq#promotion)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I can help you with the screen brightness. I've posted what worked from me [as an answer to a similar question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/541239/48105).