# Macbook starts with the screen on minimum brightness

Tags: macbook, backlight

I have a Macbook2,1 with Ubuntu 12.04. When I start the computer the back light is on and I can see all of the boot stuff. Once the GUI begins to start up the backlight is turned completely off and I can not see anything. I do however hear the little ubuntu drum beat, can then type my password and log on. Once I have done this I can then use the brightness buttons to turn the brightness back up but the logon screen is always just blackness.

I can control the brightness from the command line using

```
 echo 500 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_video/brightness
```

and I put this line into /etc/rc.local before the exit 0 but this doesnt do anything.
How can I get the brightness back up when the GUI starts up?

Comment: Since `rc.local` is run under `UID 0`, you could simplify the command to `echo 500 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_video/brightness` Why not follow it with `cp /sys/class/backlight/intel_video/brightness /tmp/brightness` so you can see if it took the 500?

Comment: Do you have any other displays plugged into your MacBook? Just eliminating the obvious...

Comment: Tried @waltinator suggestion. 500 is copied to /tmp/brightness but still dark login screen. So I guess its being adjusted after rc.local is run? And, no, nothing plugged in but the power cable.

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me:

1. Find your ACPI interface: `grep acpi_video /var/log/Xorg.0.log`
2. Get the desired brightness level: set brightness to desired level then run `cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_videoX/brightness`, substituting `X` for the ACPI number found on step 1
3. Create a `fixbrightness.conf` file: run `gksu gedit /etc/init/fixbrightness.conf` and paste the following, replacing `BRIGHTNESS_VALUE` with the number gotten from the previous step and `X` for your ACPI interface number:

   ```
   description "Sets brightness after graphics device is loaded"

   start on graphics-device-added`
   task
   exec /bin/echo BRIGHTNESS_VALUE > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_videoX/brightness
   ```
4. Save and reboot.

Source: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/fix-brightness-getting-reset-to-very.html

Answer (score 0):

Still not exactly sure how to change this setting but the last round of updates from the update manager seems to have fixed this. Will post if I can find which update did this or what setting to change.